# Automapper configuration for interesting nested object scenario

Tags: automapper, nested-class

I have an interesting scenario and the answer isn't jumping out at me. I've looked for other similar questions but none seem to address this type of issue.

Before you ask, I do not have control over the source class layout.

My source object looks like this:

```
class Class1
{
   string string1
   string string2
   string string3
   string string4
   string string5
   string string6
}
class Class2
{
   string foo
   string bar
}
class Class3 //The source object!!
{
   Class1 Inner1
   Class2 Inner2
}
```

And my destination looks like this:

```
class Destination
{
   string string1
   string string2
   string string3
   string string4
   string string5
   string string6
   string string7
}
```

In reality, Inner1 is a huge class and almost a perfect match - except for a couple exceptions. I'd like to use Automapper to directly copy everything from Inner1 to Destination using default matching, but also copy Inner2.foo to Destination.string6 and Inner2.bar to Destination.string7.

**EDIT:** I should add that right now I am mapping Inner1 to Destination and then doing a couple manual property copies outside of Automapper.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you currently have something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Inner1, Destination>();
...
var inner1 = GetInner1();
var destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(inner1);
// now do manual hydration on destination using inner2 instance...
```

You might be able to get away with this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Inner1, Destination>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Inner2, Destination>()
    .ForMember(d => d.string6, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.foo))
    .ForMember(d => d.string7, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.bar))
;
...
var inner1 = GetInner1();
var destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(inner1);

var inner2 = GetInner2();
Mapper.Map(inner2, destination);
```